# Why is correct sum of memory integers in register ax but not register eax?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, nasm

Given this program -- a student's program whom I am helping --

```
        global  _start

        section .text
_start:
        mov    ebx, people 
        mov    eax, [ebx + 2]
        add    eax, [ebx + 4]
        add    eax, [ebx + 6]
        add    eax, [ebx + 8]
        mov    ebx, [constant]
        div    bx

section .data

average     dw 0
constant    dw 5
people      dw 0, 10, 25, 55, 125
```

While porting this from Visual Studio to a Linux machine to figure out what the problem was, I ran into some questions:

1) Why does gdm display the sum 255 when `print $ax` issued, but a large number appears when `print $eax` command issued? Is that because we have added word values instead of longword values?

I did try to add into ax, rather than eax, and got the same results. I got a relocation complaint when I tried to move the initial value into ax. That's why I used eax.

2) Why is the quotient 43 when `div bx` used, but if `div ebx` used, I get the wrong answer?

As an aside, I believe I found the original problem, which was an integer overflow. Line 10 -- `mov    ebx, [constant]` -- was originally `mov ebx,constant`, which did not result in moving 5 into bx.

Comment: You are loading 32 bits (`eax`) from locations with 16 bit offsets. That gives you an overlap in the values.

Comment: The `div` works differently, check the instruction guide. Or search stack overflow (usually this pops about 2-5 times per month). And your code doesn't terminate (as long as you only step over it in debugger, that's ok, just don't run it).

Comment: @BoPersson Same thing happened -- adding the word values -- when I used ax. I tried a lot of different things.

Comment: Using `ax` only manipulates the low 16 bits, whatever is in the top 16 bits of `eax` remains. If you care, you can zero them either separately or using `movzx` for the initial load. Note, if you intend to perform the additions using 32 bit arithmetic, you will need to extend the other numbers to 32 bits too.

Comment: @Jester How do you extend the other numbers in the instruction?

Comment: To define 32bit values in memory, you can use `people: dd 0, 10, 25` ... also of course the `mov ebx,[constant]` is fetching first 2 bytes from `people` in the original code you posted. Either do `movzx ebx, word [constant]`, or again use `dd 5`.

Comment: @Ped7g I was trying to preserve the original program as it was, and rewrite as little as possible.

Comment: `movzx ecx, word [ebx + 4]; add eax, ecx` and so on.

Comment: So don't use `eax` then? (and just ignore the upper 16b of `eax`, focus on `ax` low 16bit part only. The original 16 bit code will mostly work, x86 is backward compatible. Only various `int ...` DOS services and similar will fail under linux. If you will use 32 bit registers, and add those word data (as Jester and Bo suggested), you already modified the code heavily, as it will not overflow upon reaching 65536, but it will sum values further up to 2^32-1.  Assembly is strongly typed...or how to tell it...the machine has few native types. You can't avoid them. Decide consciously, which you use.

Comment: And `mov ebx,constant` will translate by NASM into, in my BIASED opinion, the correct form of `mov ebx, "address of label constant"`. As the Intel syntax requires to mark memory access by using square brackets `[address expression]`. Unfortunately there's huge family of x86 assemblers (MASM, emu8086, TASM in MASM mode, ...) trying to be smart and acting as `mov ebx,constant` is "fetch variable". To get address in those you have to use keyword `offset`: `mov ebx,offset constant`. NASM is cleaner and requires `[]` usage instead, so you can easily see every memory access when *reading* source.

Comment: Use `p /x $eax` for hex format.  It will be clear that you have two small 16-bit values packed into your 32-bit register.  Or use `layout reg`.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for asm debugging tips with gdb.

Answer (score 3):

### A few problems

1. All the data is defined as **word** but the code treats it as **dword**.
2. Prior to the division you need to extent the dividend via `DX` or `EDX`.
3. Although the first value in the array is zero, it's probably better to also include it in the code. If ever the data changes, at least the code will remain valid!

---

### Solutions

1. Keep the data 16-bit and program accordingly

   ```
   mov    edx, people
   mov    ax, [edx]
   add    ax, [edx + 2]
   add    ax, [edx + 4]
   add    ax, [edx + 6]
   add    ax, [edx + 8]
   xor    dx, dx
   div    word ptr [constant]      ;Divide DX:AX by 5
   ...
   constant    dw 5
   people      dw 0, 10, 25, 55, 125
   ```
2. Make the data 32-bit and program accordingly

   ```
   mov    edx, people
   mov    eax, [edx]
   add    eax, [edx + 4]
   add    eax, [edx + 8]
   add    eax, [edx + 12]
   add    eax, [edx + 16]
   xor    edx, edx
   div    dword ptr [constant]     ;Divide EDX:EAX by 5
   ...
   constant    dd 5
   people      dd 0, 10, 25, 55, 125
   ```

---

See how I've avoided the use of `EBX`?

- The division can use its divider straight from memory.
- The `EDX` register (that anyway takes part in the division) can also equally fine address memory.

Less register clobbering is a good thing!

Comment: You are correct. The instructor of the course, wanted different data types. My friend, one of our interns who I am helping, believes this is why students were encouraged to write a program on a 64-bit Windows Intel System but add numbers represented as words. I added the eax instead of ax, because I wanted to see how instructions work. I don't program in Intel assembler. The last assembly language I used was MACRO32 (DEC/VAX).

Comment: Solution 3: zero-extend to 32-bit as you load from 16-bit.  `movzx eax, word [edx]` / `movzx ecx, word [edx+2]` / `add eax, ecx` / `movzx ...`.  This would be good for a big array where a smaller cache footprint is worth needing more instructions.  (Of course then you'd use SSE2 to sum it.  Or better, SSE4 for `pmovzx`)